# Distinctness of magnetic monopoles from electric monopoles

Tags: electromagnetism, charge, magnetic-monopoles

If magnetic monopoles could exist, how would they differ from electric charges?

Comment: This question is far too broad - many of the questions in the [tag:magnetic-monopoles] tag are more specific variants of this, and the answers can vary wildly with the specific model of monopole chosen.

Answer (score -1):

Besides the chemical process, it is the separation of the electric charges by a magnetic field that leads to the generation of an electric potential. And electric charges that are accelerated circularly lead to the realignment of the magnetic dipoles. I see no way to distinguish or separate the hypothetical magnetic N and S monopoles from the electric monopoles.

Even more, I find it outdated that the electron is not treated equally as an electric charge and as a magnetic dipole. You can destroy the electron, the positron, the proton and the antiproton and what you get is electro-magnetic radiation.

What you don't pay attention to is the internal structure of EM radiation. I would find it interesting if one could hypothesise the inner structure for a deeper understanding of magnetic and electric fields and EM radiation.